# Object 'Date' not found in R

Tags: r

I want to subset my data set between two distinct dates. I've loaded the data from a text file to R with ';' as separators.

```
x <- read.table("household_power_consumption.txt", sep = ";", header = TRUE)

head(x)
```

gives me this:

```
[head(x)][1]
```

The data set contains over 200000 lines so I need to subset the data of only two particular dates.
So I tried this:

```
x[Date >= as.Date("2007-02-01") | Date <= as.Date("2007-02-02")]
```

But I see the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, Date >= as.Date("2007-02-01") | Date <= as.Date("2007-02-02")) : object 'Date' not found
```

So what is the problem here? How do I subset the data?

Comment: try `x[x$Date >= as.Date("2007-02-01") & x$Date <= as.Date("2007-02-02"),]`

Comment: By default, `[.data.frame` does not operate within its frame. You need to replace `Date` with `x$Date`, or switch to, e.g., `data.table`, which _does_ operate within frame, or use `with`.

Comment: Also, 200,000 lines is getting into [`fread` territory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15058684/3576984).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

1. As discussed in the comments, the subsetting of the data frame requires a different approach. Maybe the simplest one is to use `x$Date` instead of `Date`.
2. You want to select two specific dates. For this you can either use

   ```
   x$Date == as.Date("2007-02-01") | x$Date == as.Date("2007-02-02")
   ```

   (connected with a logical `OR`), or

   ```
   x$Date >= as.Date("2007-02-01") & x$Date <= as.Date("2007-02-02")
   ```

   (connected with a logical `AND`). 
   The version in your code selects any possible date and is therefore not useful.
3. You did not specify the column(s) that you want to select. The purpose, I assume, is to select the entire row of the entries that correspond to your selection criterion. For this, you need to add a comma at the end, before closing the square bracket.

**edit**

Not knowing the format in which the column `x$Date` is stored, it may be helpful to wrap that content into `as.Date()`, too.

In summary, this should probably work:

```
x[as.Date(x$Date) >= as.Date("2007-02-01") & as.Date(x$Date) <= as.Date("2007-02-02"),]
```

Comment: I have tried this but this is the warning message that I see: incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for the ">=" ; Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.Date") for the "<="

Comment: You didn't post your data; it might help to know the output of `class(x$Date)`. But you could probably resolve this by wrapping the date into `as.Date()`, like `as.Date(x$Date) >= as.Date("2004-02-01)...`

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to use the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when reading the file with `read.csv()`. But I find that the version with `as.Date()` on either side of the `>=` and `=<` sign is better.

Comment: Had to add the factor parameter in the as.Date() function like as.Date(x$Date, factor = "%d/%m/%Y") >= as.Date("2007-02-01").. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome...I assume it was `format= "%d/%m/%Y"`. If the answer was useful to solve your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick on the left.